# Cucumber tests not running Liquibase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, liquibase

Liquibase does not run when I execute my Cucumber tests, although works fine for application and unit tests.

I have a suite of cucumber-spring tests, testing a spring-boot application.

I have recently introduced Liquibase to the application, which runs fine when I run the application or the unit tests, but does not get run when I run my cucumber tests, either from a RunCukesTest Junit class or from the cucumber-cli.

The correct application.properties files get loaded in all cases, and I do nothing special to get Liquibase to run in the standard application and tests.  It is enabled by default, and I have tried forcing enabled, but with no luck.

I have tried setting a SpringLiquibase bean in the tests, but cucumber-spring does not like this, as it does not allow further @Configuration classes.

The Liquibase jar is available on the classpath, and referencing a Liquibase type compiles fine in the cucumber steps.

The only property I set is :

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

My Cucumber test class has the signature:

```
@Ignore
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SpringConfig extends SpringBootBaseIntegrationTest implements En {
```

in `application.properties`. I have tried setting this for Cucumber `application.properties` also with no change.

Liquibase should run my changelog files as per standard application launch.

Comment: Could merge the base integration test down, try again, and include it in your post? Cucumber spring starts an application context so I would expect it to be picked up. But I am not sure about the inhertance.

Comment: Also, which version of cucumber?

Comment: Hi thanks, it seemed a weird set of things. In the end I had to put my cubes spring profile in main/resources to get picked up and applied properly. Too much magic happens around databases and connections happens to follow it all through logically.